# JUnit Test Case creation

Tags: junit, junit4

Is it possible to associate @before and @after to specific @test besides replacing @before and @after with functions and calling them from the @test?

Answer (score 0):

No, JUnit does not provide any way to associate before and after methods with specific tests. Before and after are associated with the instance of the test class. The test class is instantiated for each method annotated with @test. So before and after run before and after each test.

If you want different before and after implementations, you can simply create a new test class.

But, let's say you have a class *A* and a test class *ATest* where *ATest* has test methods that cover every method implemented by *A*. Then you can only use the before and after methods for code that applies to every test. This is actually alright - the fixture setup and teardown for the file delete test that was mentioned could be invoked at the top and bottom of that specific test; you could for example define *ATest.beforeFileDelete* or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [HierarchicalContextRunner](https://github.com/bechte/junit-hierarchicalcontextrunner/wiki) for grouping the tests.